# What is better? query (sql) or hash_equals

Tags: php, sql, hash, equals

**A)** SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password_hash = ?

**B)** `hash_equals($password_hash_real, $password_hash_user)`

Obviously, I see if there is a row selected to see if the password is correct.

Which is safer?

Comment: `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` is the way to go, no question there.

Comment: You'd have to GET the hash from the DB to properly re-hash the password with the original salt, so you might as well just `select id,username, hash where username=?` only, then compare hashes in php with password_verify().

Comment: Great, I changed my code using password_hash and password_verify. Thanks.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Tip: Add your comment as an answer and gain reputation.

Comment: I agree with Bart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking password matches isn't the job of a database. Besides, you probably want to know if the user exists, although the hash isn't the good one. So I'd do it within the PHP script.

`hash_equals()` is not meant to verify a password with a hash. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` since they add a salt and everything for you.

Comment: It's correct but @Franz solved the query. I should mark this answer as correct?

Comment: @Lucas Always good to mark an answer as correct and share rep. Right now your question is considered still unsolved